# how to integrate these commands to one command?

Tags: beamer

I use below codes to highlight where I am talking about.

```latex
\newcommand<>{\hl}[1]{{
        \alt#2{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}{#1}
}}
\onslide<1->{\hl<1>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color\\}}
\onslide<2->{\hl<2>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color\\}}
\onslide<3->{\hl<3>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color\\}}
\onslide<4->{\hl<4>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color}}
```

I think it can be simplified by a new command.
to integrate the commands, I tried code below:

```latex
\newcommand<>{\next}[1]{
 \onslide#2-{\alt#2{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}{#1}}
}
```

but that doesnt work well.

so , how to integrate these commands to one command?

Comment: Don't use `\next` as a command name to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `\temporal` macro instead of `\alt`, it allows you to define before slide, on slide and after slide alternatives:

```
\temporal<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨before slide text⟩}{⟨default text⟩}{⟨after slide text⟩}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand<>{\hl}[1]{{
   \temporal#2{}{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}{#1}
}}



\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \hl<1>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color}
  
  \hl<2>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color}
  
  \hl<3>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color}
  
  \hl<4>{when they comeout will in a yellow background color}   
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

---

(Slightly different example + animation)

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577337
\documentclass{beamer}

% \temporal<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨before slide text⟩}{⟨default text⟩}{⟨after slide text⟩}
\newcommand<>{\myOwnCommand}[1]{{
   \temporal#2{}{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}{#1}
}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item \myOwnCommand<1>{when they come out will be in a yellow background color}
    \item \myOwnCommand<2>{when they come out will be in a yellow background color}
    \item \myOwnCommand<3>{when they come out will be in a yellow background color}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: beamer is full of surprises :). Can you explain the `\newcommand<>`? Does beamer define a new type of `\newcommand`? How does the `\temporal#2` work, the `#2` is confusing. I can ask a separate question if that is better.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, beamer provides this special variation of `\newcommand`, see the user guide "9.6.1 Making Commands and Environments Overlay Specification-Aware". The `#2` stores the overlay specification, e.g. `<1>`, so `\temporal#2` expands to e.g. `\temporal<1>{...}{...}{...}`.

Comment: Thanks and happy Xmas!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Happy Xmas to you, too!